# How can I write a number in Phython in a scientific format with e-3 or e-6 etc instead of e-4 , e-8

Tags: python, numbers, scientific-notation

**How can I write a number in Phython in a scientific format with e-3 or e-6** etc instead of e-4 , e-8 etc?
For example:
My number is: 300669500.

Phyton gives me 3.006695**e+08**

I want 0.3006695**e+09**

or    300.6695**e+06**

How do I do that?